# combining angular-electron with Devextreme

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, electron, devextreme

Basically, I am trying to combine two projects into one but I am getting some errors with webpack that I dont understand.

I am trying to combine [Angular-Electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) with [Devextreme Layout](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/DevExtreme_CLI/#DevExtreme_Application/Add_the_DevExtreme_Layout_to_an_Existing_Application)

I first I tried to install all necessary dependencies by following [This](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Angular_Components/Getting_Started/Add_DevExtreme_to_an_Angular_CLI_Application/) but whenever I ran the following command:

```
npx -p devextreme-cli devextreme add devextreme-angular
```

It would throw the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'toString' of null
```

So then I tried to create the Devextreme project in a separate repo by running the following command:

```
npx -p devextreme-cli devextreme new angular-app app-name
```

and just copy over files/folders but now I get webpack errors when trying to run `npm run start` in the angular-electron app

Here is the error I get

```
angular-electron@10.0.0 start C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron
> npm-run-all -p electron:serve ng:serve


> angular-electron@10.0.0 ng:serve C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron
> ng serve -c web -o


> angular-electron@10.0.0 electron:serve C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron
> wait-on tcp:4200 && npm run electron:serve-tsc && npx electron . --serve

⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
> angular-electron@10.0.0 electron:serve-tsc C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron
> tsc -p tsconfig.serve.json

⠦ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
× ｢wdm｣: HookWebpackError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
    at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:49:9)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2496:12
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1) 
    at fn (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:427:17)
    at _next3 (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:46:1) 
    at fn (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:439:9)
    at _next2 (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:41:1)
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:59:1) 
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1) 
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:546:10
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2857:9)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:382:17
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2857:9)
-- inner error --
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1043:3)
    at CacheBackend.provideSync (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:233:32)
    at WebpackFileSystem.listPaths (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackFileSystem.js:78:24)
    at LicenseTextReader.readLicense (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\LicenseTextReader.js:37:54)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processModule (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:46:62)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:22:23
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.internalCallback (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:25:13)
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.iterateFiles (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:10:9)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:20:32
    at WebpackChunkModuleIterator.iterateModules (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackChunkModuleIterator.js:42:21)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processChunk (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:19:29)
    at _loop_1 (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:92:37)
    at WebpackCompilerHandler.iterateChunks (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:127:17)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:43:31
    at fn (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:425:10)
    at _next3 (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
× ｢wdm｣: caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1043:3)
    at CacheBackend.provideSync (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:233:32)
    at WebpackFileSystem.listPaths (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackFileSystem.js:78:24)
    at LicenseTextReader.readLicense (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\LicenseTextReader.js:37:54)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processModule (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:46:62)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:22:23
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.internalCallback (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:25:13)
    at WebpackModuleFileIterator.iterateFiles (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackModuleFileIterator.js:10:9)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:20:32
    at WebpackChunkModuleIterator.iterateModules (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackChunkModuleIterator.js:42:21)
    at PluginChunkReadHandler.processChunk (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\PluginChunkReadHandler.js:19:29)
    at _loop_1 (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:92:37)
    at WebpackCompilerHandler.iterateChunks (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:127:17)
    at C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\license-webpack-plugin\dist\WebpackCompilerHandler.js:43:31
    at fn (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:425:10)
    at _next3 (eval at create (C:\Users\americo.perez\Downloads\Repos\angular-electron\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

Basically, I created a devextreme application from scratch without electron.
Then I added electron to it after the fact and installed all of the dependencies that were required to run the command
`npm run start` according to what was in the package.json of angular-electron project.

I then used the package.json commands that were in the angular-electron repo in combination with the debugging files in the .vscode folder as a guide to get Debugging working.